# Slow loading time for a eshop built by an open source software

Tags: performance, browser, web, browser-cache, pagespeed

I am working on a eshop and the time is very long to loading

So I have check the tool to analyze

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/be-pure.com/XxvAiYMJ

and

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbe-pure.com%2F&tab=desktop

The problem is that the site seems wait a few second before actually download the resource. Are there any way to track is there any JS coding / PHP coding takes the most of time ? Or any approach to debug that

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your site and fired up Google Chrome's Developer tools. From there I navigated to the network tab and had a look at the requests coming in.

The problem isn't your server side code, it is that you have so many blocking Javascript and CSS files. For example, have a look at the image below:

[image]

I know the image above looks a little small, but your page only begins to render where the red arrow is! If you do as Google's PageSpeed [suggests](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) and minify and combine your JS and CSS files, you will only have 2 requests instead of 87 requests!

Remember that CSS and JS are [blocking](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) resources and the browser needs to download them before it can begin rendering the page.

I also thoroughly recommend doing all the things that Googles Pagespeed suggests - it will really make a difference to the performance of your site!